# Why use "worrying" in "It's no use worrying about it."

Tags: exam-questions, infinitive-vs-gerund

Recently, I came across a fill-in-the-blank.

> It's no use ______ (worry) about it.

The right answer as told by my teacher is "worrying", why is "to worry" not right?

Comment: Note that sometimes this kind of exercise or test (especially the more carefully designed ones) doesn't instruct the student to choose the only correct choice, but rather the best choice. If choosing the best choice is the instruction, then it's fair to answer *worrying*. On the other hand, if the key of the exercise/test states that *worrying* is the only correct choice, and *to worry* is always incorrect, I'd think that the exercise/test is not a well-designed one.

Answer (score 2):

It's no use is always followed by a gerund.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/it-s-no-use-doing-something

There's no rule. You need to learn each expression by itself.

You can Google expressions that are followed by gerunds.

Comment: It's no use *to deny* the possibility.

Comment: @user3169 It's no use denying the possibility. (whatever you hear in songs)

Comment: @NaokiRinmous  You're welcome.

Comment: Nowadays, the gerund is almost always used, but you'll find plenty of examples of the to-infinitive in the 19th century.

Comment: @TRomano The question was about current English, answered as such.

Comment: And the comment was added for those who might see the infinitive in a written work, where the language can be more conservative. You'll find the infinitive in 20th c. works as well.

Comment: @TRomano When answering questions asked by EFL learners, I prefer to give the answer they'll need on the exam they'll be taking, where only one option is considered correct. It's important to make the distinction to an EFL learner, otherwise he'll be totally confused. Literary references need to be qualified.

Comment: @TRomano I believe if we looked harder, we'd find such usage in some works of this century as well. But your point is a fair point.

Answer (score 1):

I think your teacher is confused probably with "there is no use -ING" construction such as

> There is no use doing something.

"It is no use worrying about it" is (far) more broadly used than "It is no use to worry about it". However, it doesn't necessarily mean you can never use the latter.

The *it* is an [expletive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/expletive) (See No. 2 definition) pronoun used as a dummy subject and both *to infinitive* or *gerund* could be used in the sentence.

Your teacher's confusion could have been caused by the very popular idiom "It's no use crying over spilled (spilt) milk".

Sometimes, it is difficult to explain when we should use gerund in place of to infinitive as [their functions overlap in many cases](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/gerunds.htm). It is even more difficult to explain why using either of them is wrong or sounds unidiomatic.

As far as I understand, when an expletive pronoun *it* is used, it is okay to use both of them. But in the case of "it is no use" construction, gerund is much preferred. When "there" is used as a dummy subject, a gerund should be used.

A side note: Can you show this answer to your teacher and get his/her feedback and let me know it in a comment?

Comment: :D She's still saying that "to worry" is a wrong answer, as "worrying" is the only right usage according to the rule in her textbook. Anyway, thanks for confirming.

Comment: @NaokiRinmous Your teacher is right. It's no use cannot be followed by a full infinitive.

Comment: @NaokiRinmous Well, I would be hesitant to use the word "wrong" when it makes sense. It might be less idiomatic, but I don't think it is wrong.

Comment: An example by Ernest Hemingway: [*It's no use to walk ahead and find there's nothing coming behind you.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BHRt-c_FsSQC&pg=PA373)